# Trying to wire switch outlet combo to existing two outlet. But the outlets each have 3 wires

Tags: switch, neutral

[image]I have 2 outlets, I want to replace with switch outlet combo (outlet always hot).

But looking online, I keep seeing everything has only one white neutral, but in my case, both outlets have a black hot and white neutral wire along with the grounds twisted together.  In other words, each outlet has its own romex cable with 3 wires.

Am I not able to replace this outlet with a switch combo because it has 2 neutrals?

This is confusing me.  Thanks.

Comment: Are the outlets on different breakers?  How about a picture of the outlet box and combo switch.

Comment: Added pic to original post. Sorry, I guess I meant one outlet 2 receptacles?  So I just switched off one breaker.  Old outlet on left, switch combo on right.

Comment: Also from the looks of it, it isn't going directly to the breaker but both romex cables are coming from 2 other outlets.  The top receptacle wires are coming from an outlet directly right of it, and the bottom receptacle are coming from a third outlet even further right.  There are about 4 outlets connected to one breaker and the one I opened up appears to be the last outlet in the chain of outlets.

Comment: Can you clarify just what you intend the switch to do in this case if you want to keep the single outlet "always hot"?

Comment: You're removing a GFCI outlet.  Where are all these outlets on this breaker located?  What will the switch control if the outlet's  always hot?

Comment: I wanted to hard wire cabinet lights.  There is nothing wet on this side of the counter.  Actually, the whole house is not up to code as far as gfci goes.  The sink is in an island and none of the outlets had gfci which I had to replace with gfci.  The bathrooms had no gfci which I had to replace as well.  The only 2 gfci inside the entire house is this one side of kitchen counter that has nothing really other than an oven on the left on its own circuit and a fridge on the right.

Comment: I'm about to say screw it and just get a standalone switch and wire the switch onto the top receptacle.

Comment: I take it one cable is an always-hot feed in and the other is a switched-hot feed out?

Comment: Ok, I realized why the gfci is there.  It is the gfci for the island kitchen sink outlet.  I just found this out by using an outlet tester and testing the sink gfci which I added earlier.  The new gfci didn't trigger, the one shown in picture triggered.  But since I replaced the kitchen outlet with gfci, I theoretically no longer need the gfci that I pictured (that is removed in the picture).  I'm thinking just changing it to regular outlet and powering my cabinet light off of it along with a standalone switch via double gang box.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Let's take a look at what we have here

You have 2 cables, and each one has (presumably) hot, neutral and ground. It is normal for all grounds simply to be all tied to each other;

The old device is definitely a GFCI or AFCI, *no doubt of it*.

So what you're viewing as "each socket powered by a separate cable" is actually the GFCI device being what it is.  It has one hot/neutral pair (called "LINE") that inputs power from the supply, and from there, power goes through the GFCI electronics. The output of the GFCI electronics provides a **zone of protection**, and that goes to the other hot-neutral pair (called "LOAD") to be carried onward to other outlets.  It also protects the sockets on GFCI *receptacles* (not every GFCI device is a receptacle).

So each cable does not power each socket at all. The positions are sheer coincidence. Both sockets are connected together along with the LOAD wires, and all together are on the protected side of the GFCI.

**Any socket-type outlet in the protected zone requires a "GFCI Protected" sticker.**

And this actually caused you to waste a lot of money.

### GFCI Roundup

It sounds like you have way more GFCIs than you have circuits. That will cause you problems when a GFCI trips for cause ,because all the upstream GFCIs will also trip, and they are very picky about reset sequence.

[See this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/178088/now-i-realize-i-used-too-many-gfci-outlets-how-can-i-reclaim-them) for how to untangle that.

Now that you have a pile of GFCIs, identify every circuit in your house that doesn't have *any GFCIs at all*, and spread the love by finding the first receptacle in the chain. However do not put GFCI protection on safety devices such as refrigerators, radon pumps, fire alarms, etc. where a nuisance trip will poison or kill people.

### Grandfathering: you can't *downgrade*

ALL kitchen receptacles are required to be GFCI.  Even if this outlet was grandfathered, you can't **downgrade**: you can't remove protection you already do have. This means 2 things:

- This receptacle *must* remain GFCI
- The downline circuit *must* be protected by GFCI

Now as the other answer describes, the other receps could be protected merely by siting a GFCI at the next recep. However, this recep still needs protection.

Fortunately, a dual GFCI+receptacle+switch *is indeed* an item that is sold.  It is exactly what you have there (the new one) but with GFCI protection on the receptacle.   The wiring *to the screws* is the same as the old GFCI receptacle.  The switch is not on any screws; it is handled as two **pigtail wires** which you can do with as you please. *Noting that hardwired lighting does not need GFCI protection*.

That 20A-keyed socket+switch is an expensive beast, having just bought one myself. Take it back.  You may find the incremental cost to a GFCI version of that isn't much more than what you are returning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So apparently every single kitchen outlet is protected because there are 2 original gfcis, and all outlets around were connected to it via load connection.  I removed the redundant gfci I installed a while ago near the sink.  Kept the original gfci that was pictured (and removed at the time).  Returned the outlet/switch combo.  Bought a 20 amp switch, connected it to the gfci in a 2 gang box.  Its all working at intended.