Why are there two cables connected to this GFCI outlet?
I'm trying to add a new GFCI outlet by splitting and using pigtails off an existing GFCI outlet. However, when I opened out the junction box I noticed that there are two sets of wires attached to the existing GFCI outlet.
Why is this set up this way?
Can I just take one of the set off and use that for my new outlet?





Do you understand the concept of line and load in this scenario, as labeled on the outlet and referenced in the instructions for the new one? Have a look at the instructions for your new outlet. No, you can't just undo what's there. It's there for a reason.

May I ask why you're adding a second GFCI outlet to the circuit? Once you understand line and load you may realize that this is unnecessary--you can protect a downstream standard outlet with this outlet.

Here's the reason why. The existing outlet is sink area of the bathroom. On the other side of the wall is the toilet area of the bathroom, sectioned off by a closing door. We want to add another outlet in the other room where the toilet is about 2 feet over.

And no, I'm not familiar with Line and Load, but will look it up and take another look at instructions. I just got confused because when I've changed regular outlets (I've changed about 4 in the house), there are on one set of wires going to the outlet. Meaning 1 black, 1 white, and 1 ground. I haven't changed a GFI oulet before or looked at it's wiring very closely until now.

Plenty of outlets have a cable coming in and a cable going out to another. This isn't odd in that regard. What is different is that the downstream outlet is also protected.

A good read on LINE vs LOAD https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/293925/55930

GFCI outlets have two sets of connectors: Line and Load.
The Line terminals receive power from the breaker/fuse box. The Load terminals carry power onto other outlet(s). These “downstream” outlets are also protected by this GFCI.
If you want to add a separate GFCI outlet, you’ll need to identify the wires connected to the Line terminals and connect the new wires there. Looking at the photos, it looks like you’re in luck: these are designed to accept two wires each. Otherwise, you’d need to pull out the wires and add pigtail wires to connect everything.
On the other hand, you could add another standard outlet and have it protected by this GFCI. To do this connect the new wires in parallel with the Load wires. Note that you must label the new outlet “GFCI protected”. I’d also suggest labeling it with the location of the GFCI.
To answer your last question, you wil need an additional cable to go to the new outlet.

Depending on where the new outlet is going and where the second outlet powered from the GFCI is, it might be better to add new cable from the second.

Are you saying that the second set of wires are going out to other outlets?

@ptownbro -- the second set of wires, connected to the "load" connectors, feeds to another outlet or outlets; they're ordinary outlets that are protected by this GFCI outlet.

To further clarify, if you are trying to add another outlet downstream of this one, it does not need to be GFCI, because this existing outlet will handle that function (assuming you connect/pigtail the new outlet to the LOAD terminals—but if you don't, neither outlet will work anyway).

Thanks. I appreciate your help on this. I was able to get it all connected. The second set of wires were leading to another outlet in the same room. I just completed or keep the circurt/line (so-to-speak) going and it is working. Had a electrician help and he okay'd it. Thanks!

You might look at cars and presume all cars are gasoline powered. No, "gasoline power" does not define cars and there are other options. Similarly, you might look at GFCIs and presume all GFCIs are "GFCI + receptacle combo devices".  GFCIs come in many forms - GFCI+receptacle, GFCI+breaker, GFCI+switch, GFCI as switch, and GFCI only. They're even built into EV "chargers"!   All of them provide the "downline protection" feature you just learned about.
On the vast majority of GFCIs, they use a splice feature called "Screw-and-clamp". This allows each screw to screw down and clamp up to 2 wires each.   So on your setup, you can add an additional pair of wires to either the LINE side screws (if you do not want downline protection) or the LOAD side screws (if you do want downline protection).
Never put a GFCI in the downline protected area of another GFCI - resetting it after a trip will be very difficult and confusing.
Marking downline outlets is mandatory.  You'll thank me later when the receptacle goes dead for no apparent reason and you find you can fix it easily instead of hiring a pro.  You can use the ugly "GFCI Protected" stickers provided, or any other marking method which is not handwritten. I like P-touch or Brother labelmakers on a white cover plate.
Also, let's talk about a Code issue. Code requires that circuits which serve bathroom receptacles in the workspace area (i.e. bathroom counter etc. where one might plug in a hair dryer) -- circuits which serve those must not serve anything else.  To be more specific, for a circuit which serves bathroom workspace areas, either:

it serves ONLY bathroom workspace area receptacles in any number of bathrooms -or-
It serves ONLY receptacles and lighting loads in THIS bathroom.

I wasn't clear where you were extending this circuit to, but if it's outside the bathroom, no go.
